# Angular: use a select with a lot of options

Tags: angular, html-select

I usually use Select with 3 or 4 options like this:

```html
<select name="car_color" [(ngModel)]="car.color">
    <option value='BL'>Blue</option>
    <option value='RD'>Red</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that I have a list of 120 colors. I could put them all the same way but I want to do it the proper way

Answer (score 1):

You can use component class for storing information about options

```
class Component {
  public items = [{name: 'Blue', value: 'BL'}, {name: 'Red', value: 'Red'}];

}


<select name="car_color" [(ngModel)]="car.color">
   <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value">
     {{ item.name }}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to your component an array of car colors with value and text and afterwards you can do a loop in your html to display all options like so :

Component:

```
carColors = [{text:'Blue', value: 'BL'},{text:'Red', value: 'RD'}];
```

Html:

```
 <select name="car_color" [(ngModel)]="car.color">
    <option *ngFor="let carColor of carColors" value=car.value>{{carColor.text}}</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply loop through your list :

> example.html

```
<select name="car_color" [(ngModel)]="car.color">
  <option *ngFor="let color of colorList"[value]="color.value">{{color.name}}</option>
</select>
```

> example.ts

```
colorList = [
  { value: 'BL', name: 'blue' },
  { value: 'RD', name: 'red' }
  …
];
```

Comment: how this is different from answer given below?

Comment: @jitender It's pretty the same logic, we just answered at the same time without knowing each others response

Comment: there is diff of 3 minutes please try upvote other ans instead of posting same ans again bcs that's only creating a mess here